# Does the number of trials and probability in binomial distribution should be independent variables?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Let's say that the number of trials and probability of success are a function of some variable **t** i.e, N(t) = f(t) and p(t)=g(t). Can we still use a binomial distribution in this case?

Comment: Then the number of success Y(t) still follows the binomial distribution Bin(N(t),p(t)).

Comment: It depends: are the trials independent?

Comment: Even if independent, shouldn't we say that $Y$ is binomial *given* N(t),p(t) in general?

Comment: @whuber I am generating a number of trials using a binomial distribution in which the success probability is given by c*t, where c is some constant. My problem is that my success probability p is also a function of t.

Comment: That's not a problem.  What matters is whether your trials are independent.  When they are, the number of successes has a Binomial distribution; when they aren't, the number of successes depends on how the trials are interdependent.  The fact that you can express $N$ and $p$ as functions of some other variable is irrelevant.  What is unclear is what you might mean by "use" a binomial distribution: use it for what purpose??

Comment: Are you proposing a sequence of Bernoulli trials ($N=1$ and varying $p$) or a set of binomial experiments $X_i\sim \text{Bin}(N_t,p_t)$ for $t=1,2,\ldots,m$, with $N_t$ and $p_t$ varying over time? In either case it matters whether there's dependence between trials or between experiments. In either case, you also need to specify whether you're interested in the distribution of the collection of rvs or in their sum (i.e. in $X=(X_1,X_2,...,X_m)^\prime$ or  $S=X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_m$.in relation to the second case)

Comment: @whuber I am using the binomial distribution to generate a set of "random" values for simulation purposes. Essentially I am using Python's numpy binomial function to generate data.
x = np.random.binomial(events,prob_of_detection,1)
I want to know whether this is allowed if both events and prob_of_detection are a function of the same parameter.